# Where does Airbnb store it´s places?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

I want to know how does Airbnb store the renting rooms geographic position information.

They store it in a Google service or in it´s own servers?

Comment: Is more concrete now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com). In concrete you can be interested in [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/).

You can add a `GeoPt` to an `Entity` and perform geospatial queries. From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch):

> To add a GeoPt property to an entity, use the GeoPt class, specifying latitude and longitude:
>
> ```
> Entity station = new Entity("GasStation");
> station.setProperty("brand", "Ocean Ave Shell");
> station.setProperty("location", new GeoPt(37.7913156f, -122.3926051f));
> datastore.put(station);
> ```
>
> Use the datastore query filter `StContainsFilter` to test if a `GeoPt` is contained in a given `GeoRegion`, for example:
>
> ```
> // Testing for containment within a circle
> GeoPt center = new GeoPt(latitude, longitude);
> double radius = r; // Value is in meters.
> Filter f1 = new StContainsFilter("location", new Circle(center, radius));
> Query q1 = new Query("GasStation").setFilter(f1);
>
> // Testing for containment within a rectangle
> GeoPt southwest = new GeoPt(swLat, swLon);
> GeoPt northeast = new GeoPt(neLat, neLon);
> Filter f2 = new StContainsFilter("location", new Rectangle(southwest, northeast));
> Query q2 = new Query("GasStation").setFilter(f2);
> ```